# Instantiation when creating methods dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have some JSON data, and I'm trying to create classes and methods dynamically based on that data:

```
var classes = JSON.parse(data);
var classesObj = {};

for(var c in classes){

  var methods = classes[c].methods;
  var methodsObj = {};

  for(var m in methods){

    methodsObj[m] = function(args){

      return methods[m].property;
    }

  }
 classesObj[c] = methodsObj; 
}

return classesObj;
```

But my problem is if I call something like

```
firstClass.firstMethod()
```

The property that is returned is actually from `lastClass.lastMethod()` I'm pretty sure it's an instantiation problem, but I just can't seem to figure out where to go from here.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in jsFiddle?

Comment: Can you post a simple example of the "data"

Comment: I think u can do: var p =methods[m].property; and later return p; because otherwise it will (run-/executiontime) lookup last values from methods[m]. Ps. sorry im mobile :$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the anonymous variables (c and m) are bound to the same variable outside of the your anonymous function. See [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).